# How does the hierarchy of the Elite 10 Council work?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

Do these seat rankings indicate one's cooking level or skill? If so, which seat represents the best cook?

I was trying to figure out if Seat 1 > Seat 10 or vice versa, but I couldn't find anything nor remember which seat is better to have. It seems like Seat 1 is probably the best seat since Doujima and Saiha were portrayed to be the best cooks in Seats 1 and 2, but I just can't find anything explicitly saying Seat 1 is the best.

Comment: I don't think its been stated, yet. Only three of the seats have been revealed at this point, and while I don't remember the chapter atm, I think its been implied that each seat represents something about cooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it was never really clear which seat was considered the best, the latest chapter 47 confirms Seat 1 is the best as Seat 1 gets special recognition. [image]